# JQUERY applying css format to all records in php while loop table instead of ones matching my criteria

Tags: php, jquery, css

i have a column in a table and i want values that are less than 0.65 to be highlighted in red color. the code i have applied in jquery is as follows

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.tests').each(function(){
        var one= $('.tests').val();
        if (one<0.65) 
        {
             $('.tests').css("background-color", "red")
        }
    });
    
});
```

the problem is the entire column is getting the red color and not just the value that fall  in this criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Alright im editing post and adding snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.tests').each(function(){
        var one= $(this).val();
        if (one<0.65) 
        {
             $(this).css("background-color", "red")
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="tests" value="0.54">
<input type="text" class="tests" value="0.44">
<input type="text" class="tests" value="0.94">
<input type="text" class="tests" value="0.84">
<input type="text" class="tests" value="0.82">
<input type="text" class="tests" value="0.54">
```

If its not working for you, please add HTML, maybe theres something wrong there.

Comment: ` $('.tests').css(...);` should also be `$(this).css()`. Again, $('.tests') refers to all the inputs that have .tests class, $(this) refers to current loop element.

Comment: sorry for disappointing again. I replaced $('.tests').css(...);` with  $(this).css(). THis time, the red color has vanihsed from the entire column.

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.tests').each(function(){
            var one = $(this).val();
            if (one<0.65) 
            {
                 $(this).css("background-color", "red")
            }
        });
        
    });

but still the entire column is red

Comment: Check out the answer, i edited it, check the snippet.

Comment: following is the code of table i added for which there is a column with a class named tests. 

<tr>
    <td><?php echo($i); ?></td>
    <td id="test"><?php echo($j); ?></td>
    <td class="tests"><?php echo(round($jq,2)); ?></td>
    <td id="test"><?php echo($jr); ?></td>
    
   </tr>

Comment: this table is in a php while loop

Comment: td doesn't have .val(). Try using $(this).text();

Comment: superb. i have to say thank you so so much. it just worked so well. thanks a zillion. made my day mate. GOd bless you